# Loop through files in a folder and check if they have different extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a folder that contains files; each document should have .pdf and .xml format. I need to write a BAT file to run from a scheduled task to verify that both documents exist for each.

My logic is:

1. loop through files in the folder
2. strip each file to its name without extension
3. check that same name files exist for both .xml and pdf.
4. if not mark a flag variable as problem
5. when done, if the flag variable is marked, send an Email notification

I know how to use blat to sending email, but I'm having trouble to execute the loop. I found a way to get path and file name without extension but can't merge them.

I've used batch files a few time, before but I'm far from an expert. What am I missing?

Here's the code I have so far:

```
set "FolderPath=E:\TestBat\Test\"
echo %FolderPath%

for %%f in (%FolderPath%*) do (
  set /p val=<%%f

For %%A in ("%%f") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set Name=%%~nxA
)
echo Folder is: %Folder%
echo Name is: %Name%
if NOT EXIST %FolderPath%%name%.xml
set flag=MISSING
if NOT EXIST %FolderPath%%name%.pdf
set flag=MISSING
)

echo %Flag%
pause
```

Comment: What are you trying to find -- orphaned `.pdf` files or orphaned `.xml` files, or could both file types be orphaned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for fancy code for a task such as this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "FolderPath=E:\TestBat\Test"
If /I Not "%CD%"=="%FolderPath%" PushD "%FolderPath%" 2>Nul||Exit/B
Set "flag="
For %%A In (*.pdf *.xml) Do (
    If /I "%%~xA"==".pdf" (If Not Exist "%%~nA.xml" Set "flag=MISSING")
    If /I "%%~xA"==".xml" (If Not Exist "%%~nA.pdf" Set "flag=MISSING")
)
If Defined flag Echo=%flag%
Timeout -1
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that's what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this :

```
set "FolderPath=E:\TestBat\Test\"
pushd "%FolderPath%"

for %%a in (*.xml) do (
  if exist "%%~na.pdf"(
     echo ok
  ) else (
     rem do what you want here
     echo Missing
     )
)

popd
```

Comment: I added pause in the end but when I run the .bat it still shuts down automatically.

Comment: @StomStom He is missing a `/r` after the `for` it seems. This at least helped me...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set "FolderPath=E:\TestBat\Test\"
echo !FolderPath!

for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir !FolderPath! /B`) do (
  set /p val=<%%f
  For %%A in ("%%f") do (
    Set Folder=%%~dpA
    Set name=%%~nxA
  )
  echo Folder is: !Folder! 
  echo Name is: !name! 
  if NOT EXIST !FolderPath!!name!.xml set flag=MISSING 
  if NOT EXIST !FolderPath!!name!.pdf set flag=MISSING
)

echo Flag: !flag!
pause

endlocal
```

You should reformat your code and keep in mind that the grama for batch file is critical. BTW, if you are trying to update the existing batch variable and read it later, you should enable `localdelayedexpansion` and use `!` instead of `%`.

Comment: Hi,I run this code, currently the folder has correct content but this is what I get: E:\TestBat\Test\ The system cannot find the file specified. Folder is: E:\TestBat\ Name is: IN01002002126.pdf The system cannot find the file specified. Folder is: E:\TestBat\ Name is: IN01002002126.xml The system cannot find the file specified. Flag: MISSING Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: Actually, `%~nxA` means name with extension, you can just use `%~nA` to retreive the right name. I'm not just wrting this script for you, I'm teaching you about batch script. So please check my answer together with yours, you'll learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```dos
@echo off
pushd "E:\TestBat\Test" || exit /B 1
for %%F in ("*.pdf") do if not exist "%%~nF.xml" echo %%~nxF
for %%F in ("*.xml") do if not exist "%%~nF.pdf" echo %%~nxF
popd
```

This returns all files that appear orphaned, that is, where the file with the same name but the other extension (`.pdf`, `.xml`) is missing. To implement a variable `FLAG` to indicate there are missing files, simply append `& set "FLAG=missing"` to each `for` line and ensure `FLAG` is empty initially. Then you can check it later by simply using `if defined FLAG`.

*Note:* This does not cover the e-mail notification issue. Since I do not know the BLAT tool you mentioned, I have no clue how you want to transfer the listed files to it (command line arguments, temporary file, or *STDIN* stream?).

---

In case there is a huge number of files in the target directory, another approach might be better in terms of performance, provided that the number of file system accesses is reduced drastically (note that the above script accesses the file system within the `for` loop body by `if exist`, hence for every iterated file individually). So here is an attempt relying on a temporary file and the `findstr` command:

```dos
@echo off
pushd "E:\TestBat\Test" || exit /B 1
rem // Return all orphaned `.pdf` files:
call :SUB "*.pdf" "*.xml"
rem // Return all orphaned `.xml` files:
call :SUB "*.xml" "*.pdf"
popd
exit /B

:SUB  val_pattern_orphaned  val_pattern_missing
set "LIST=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp"
> "%LIST%" (
    rem // Retrieve list of files with one extension:
    for %%F in ("%~2") do (
        rem /* Replace the extension by the other one,
        rem    then write the list to a temporary file;
        rem    this constitutes a list of expected files: */
        echo(%%~nF%~x1
    )
)
rem /* Search actual list of files with the other extension
rem    for occurrences of the list of expected files and
rem    return each item that does not match: */
dir /B /A:-D "%~1" | findstr /L /I /X /V /G:"%LIST%"
rem // Clean up the temporary file:
del "%LIST%"
exit /B
```

To understand how it works, let us concentrate on the first sub-routine call `call :SUB "*.pdf" "*.xml"` using an example; let us assume the target directory contains the following files:

> ```
> AlOnE.xml
> ExtrA.pdf
> sAmplE.pdf
> sAmplE.xml
> ```

So in the `for` loop a list of `.xml` files is gathered:

> ```
> AlOnE.xml
> sAmplE.xml
> ```

This is written to a temporary file but with the extensions `.xml` replaced by `.pdf`:

> ```
> AlOnE.pdf
> sAmplE.pdf
> ```

The next step is to generate a list of actually existing `.pdf` files:

> ```
> ExtrA.pdf
> sAmplE.pdf
> ```

This is piped into a `findstr` command line, that searches this list for search strings that are gathered from the temporary file, returning non-matching lines only. In other words, `findstr` returns only those lines of the input list that do not occur in the temporary file:

> ```
> ExtrA.pdf
> ```

To finally get also orphaned `.xml` files, the second sub-routine call is needed.

Since this script uses a temporary file containing a file list which is processed once by `findstr` to find any orphaned files per extension, the overall number of file system access operations is lower. The weakest part however is the `for` loop (containing string concatenation operations).